# Bivariate Gaussian Independence

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

This is a homework problem.

Consider the transformation given by

z = ax + by

w = cx + dy

Define the following general bivariate Gaussian distribution:

$$
f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2 \pi \sigma^{2}\sqrt{1-\rho}}e^{-Q(x)} \\
Q(x) = \frac{1}{2 \pi \sigma^{2}1-\rho^{2}}[x^{2}-2 \rho xy + y^{2}]
$$

The following is my solution. Please tell me if I am correct and if not what I have done wrong.

$
\begin{bmatrix}z  \\w  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}a & b \\c & d \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\y \end{bmatrix} 
$

$
\begin{bmatrix}x  \\y  \end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{ad-bc}\begin{bmatrix}d & -b \\-c & a \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}z \\w \end{bmatrix} 
$

$J(x,y) = det\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\c & d \end{bmatrix} = ab-bc$

$$
f_{zw}(z,w) = f_{xy}(g_1^{-1}(z,w), g_2^{-1}(z,w))\frac{1}{|J(x,y)|} 
$$

$
g_1^{-1}(z,w)= \frac{1}{ad-bc}(dz-bw) 
$

$
g_2^{-1}(z,w) =\frac{1}{ad-bc}(aw-cz) 
$

$
let \hspace{4mm}r = \frac{1}{ad-bc}
$

$$
Q = \frac{1}{2 \pi \sigma^{2}1- \rho^{2}}[r^{2}(dz-bw)^{2}-\rho r^{2}(aw-cz)(dz-bw) + r^{2}(aw-cz)^{2}]
$$

$$
= \frac{1}{2 \pi \sigma^{2}1- \rho^{2}}[r^{2}(d^{2}z^{2}-2dzbw+b^{2}w^{2} - 2 \rho(awdz - awbw - czdz +bwcz) + a^{2}w^{2}-2awcz +c^{2}z^{2})]
$$

$$
= \frac{r^{2}}{2 \pi \sigma^{2}1- \rho^{2}}[(d^{2} +2 \rho cd + c^{2})z^{2} +(b^{2} + 2 \rho ab + a^{2})w^{2}-(2db +2 \rho ad + 2 \rho bc  +2ac)wz]
$$

for independence we need the coefficient of the wz term to equal zero

$$
2db +2 \rho ad + 2 \rho bc +2 ac = 0 \\
db + \rho ad + \rho bc + ac = 0 \\
\rho(ad+bc) = -(db+ac) \\
\rho = -\frac{db +ac}{ad+bc}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the problem is to determine the conditions on $\ a,b,c,\ $ and $\ d\ $ for which $\ z\ $ and $\ w\ $ are independent.  However, I believe there are errors in your definition of $\ f\ $. I'm presuming it should be
$$
f(x,y)=\frac{e^{-Q(x,y)}}{2\pi\sigma\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\ ,
$$
where
$$
Q(x,y)=\frac{x^2-2\rho xy+y^2}{2\sigma^2\big(1-\rho^2\big)}\ .
$$
With $\ f\ $ thus defined, $\ x,y\ $ are bivariate Gaussian variates with zero means and covariance matrix
$$
\Sigma=\sigma^2\pmatrix{1&\rho\\\rho&1}\ .
$$
If you know the theorem that affine transformations of multivariate Gaussian variates are must also be multivariate Gaussian, you don't need to transform the density to find the covariance of $\ z\ $ and $\ w\ $.  You can just appeal to the result that the covariance matrix of $\ (z,w)\ $ must be
$$
A\Sigma A^\intercal=\sigma^2\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}\pmatrix{1&\rho\\\rho&1}\pmatrix{a&c\\b&d}\ .\\
$$
The covariance of $\ w\ $ and $\ z\ $ is the common value of the off-diagonal elements of this matrix, which I get to be $\ \sigma^2\big(ac+bd+(bc+ad)\rho\big)\ $, and this is zero when
$$
\rho=-\frac{db+ac}{ad+bc}\ ,
$$
just as you've found by your method.

Apart from the errors in the coefficients of $\ f\ $ and $\ Q\ $, your method looks ok to me, although I didn't check all the algebra.  It also has the advantage that you don't need to appeal to the theorem I quoted above, because you effectively prove it for the bivariate case as part of your argument.